# python scripts which can access c++ data structures

Tags: python, c++

I have an application which contains *.cpp, *.h files which I am compiling using scons to generate the executable (.exe) file using Microsoft visual studio builder. I am using python subprocess.Popen function to run the application. 
I would like to have a python script which can access to read/write data to the structures passed as function parameters in c++ files. I don't know if its possible using python subprocess module. I checked using python ctypes but I was not able to add multiple include files. 
I need inputs on how to achieve such a functionality to have multiple python scripts to read different data structures.

Comment: Processes should be regarded as a black box with respect to other processes.

Comment: You can achieve something similar if you use some sort of a technology that uses an IDL (Interface Description Language) like Apache Thrift, or Google Protocol buffers. Thrift, for example will handle the conversion of the internal data structures to external data and also the socket communication.

Comment: Not possible with subprocess.  What are you trying to do, ultimately? perhaps there's another way to do it?

Comment: I really appreciate your inputs. I am looking for a way to develop an interface between the C application and a python script.

Comment: I have a c application which accesses a .dll and sends some data to the hardware and i want to store the response of the hardware based on the inputs i give.

Comment: Currently i am manually entering the data in the data fields of the c data structures and build the application and run it. I want to automate it by using multiple python script and call any script i want i from a main python script based on what i want to do. Could any of you tell me how to achieve such a thing.?

Comment: You'll want to modify your C code to take input of some kind before you can use it from python. Either [write your own python extension](https://docs.python.org/3.4/extending/extending.html) that can wrap your library, have your program implement some communications protocol, or as a quick-and-dirty hack use stdin and stdout.